# Multiple str_replace?

Tags: php

I'm trying to replace a URL in CodeIgniter that has certain parameters.  Not that CI should matter at this point as I have the best part of it working.

Lets say my URL is :

```
?device=field1-field2_field3+field4
```

By echoing out $devicelink2 that should show:

```
field1 field2.field3*field4
```

Currently it works with everything but replacing the +.  For some reason it replaces + with a space.

However I can't get that working using the below code.  Any ideas?

```
    $device = $this->input->get('device');
    $devicelink = str_replace("-"," ",$device);
    $devicelink1 = str_replace("_",".",$devicelink);
    $devicelink2 = str_replace("+","*",$devicelink1);
```

Comment: Is "can't get it working" the best you can do to describe your problem? If you expect the same level of detail in the answer, then the answer is, "you need to fix it".

Comment: Yeah ok ok, was editing it as you wrote this as I realised I hadn't described my actual issue

Comment: What does `echo $this->input->get('device');` yield? `field1-field2_field3+field4`? Have you then tried `echo str_replace(array('-', '_', '+'), array(' ', '.', '*'), $this->input->get('device'));`?

Comment: Yeah, in CodeIgniter $this->input->get('device') is the same as $_GET['device'].  I will try that now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`+` in a query string actually represents a space character, so with this (very odd) query string:

```
?device=field1-field2_field3+field4
```

`$this->input->get('device')` is equal to `field1-field2_field3 field4`

To answer your literal question of how to get your desired output with this exact query string:

```
$device = $this->input->get('device');
$devicelink = str_replace(" ", "*", $device);
$devicelink1 = str_replace("_", ".", $devicelink);
$devicelink2 = str_replace("-", " ", $devicelink1);
```

Or:

```
$devicelink2 = str_replace(array(' ', '_', '-'), array('*', '.', ' '), $device);
```

If you are having trouble just getting these characters into the original query string, just make sure to encode it properly:

```
?device=field1+field2.field3%2Afield4
```

See PHP's native `urlencode` function for help with this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Thanks will give it a shot.  Understand its odd, however I needed a way to distinguish between a space, a hypen, a dot and a ampersand when passing it through a URL as I couldn't use dots or ampersands in the URL itself, hence using _ and + instead

Comment: Why can't you use dots or ampersands in the URL? Remember that what you see in the URL is simply encoded, you should be able to use any value you need.

Comment: I thought there was a best practice where not to use dots or ampersands in a string in the URL.  For instance some of mine could have been page?device=samsung-at&t-galaxy-s-ii-skyrocket or page?device=samsung-galaxy-tab-10.1

Comment: Thought so, this would mess up my SEO, or would search engines see %26 as &

Comment: Good question, I'm not sure. Might be something to look up/ask on [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).  I have very strong doubts that it would affect you negatively.

Comment: Let me know if you do find the answer, I'm interested.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35426/how-would-a-search-engine-see-url-encoded-characters/35427?iemail=1#35427

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$search  = array('-', '_', '+');
$replace = array(' ', '.', '*');
$subject = $this->input->get('device');

$deviceLink = str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

str_replace accepts arrays well. 
str_replace(array('she', 'loves', 'me'), array('he' , 'hates', 'you'), 'she loves me not you');

str_replace would return "he hates you not you". (horrible examples huh?).

If you enter an array to search and an string as the replacement, it will replace all array values with the given string from the hay stack.

Or if you enter 2 arrays with same number of elements in it, elements from 'search' array will be replaced with their respective replacement value.

$devicelink = str_replace(array('-', '_', '+'), array(' ', '.', '*'), $device);